# Расширить список А, добавив в конце элементы списка в квадрате

Tags: python

Есть произвольный список,содержащий произвольные значения типа int, float

```
a = [1, 4, 34.5]
new = []
for i in a:
    new.append(i ** 2)
a.extend(new)
print(a)
```

Но может быть есть варианты получше?

Comment: И в чём у вас сложность? Возвести в квадрат элементы списка можете? А добавить в конец старого списка этот новый список? Это же элементарная задача, причём её можно несколькими способами сделать.

Comment: a = [1, 4, 34.5]
new = []
for i in a:
    new.append(i ** 2)
a.extend(new)
print(a)

Comment: a = [1, 4, 34.5]
print(a + [i ** 2 for i in a])

Comment: `a.extend([i ** 2 for i in a])`. Квадратные скобки нельзя опускать!

Answer (score 1):

Лучше только если использовать **списковое сокращение**, которое написать прямо аргументом `a.extend([...])`, тогда у вас всё решение в одну строчку поместится (не считая строки инициализации и строки вывода на печать). Я в общем-то на этот вариант намекал в своём комментарии.

Но так то можно и прямо в исходный список делать `append` новых элементов в цикле, это тоже очевидный вариант (только там возможна проблема с тем, что вы итерируетесь по списку, который меняете, но это решается взятием копии списка для итерирования).